# Functional analysis completeness proof

Tags: functional-analysis

Heres a proof for $(C^{0}[0,1],\left \| . \right \|_{\infty })$ being complete.
[image: n]

In red: Why does $f_k$ being a cauchy sequence imply that it converges? I thought the implication only holds the other way around (i.e. all convergent sequences are cauchy).

In green: Why are they showing that $f_k$ converges to $f$ uniformly. In the usual proofs ive seen of completeness they let a sequence of a sequence (i.e $(f_k)_p$ converge to a function in the vector space wrt to the norm but here $f_k$ isnt a sequence of a sequence so im not sure why they've done that.

Comment: May I know how did you draw the color rectangles to indicate in the proof?

Answer (score 1):

In red: We know $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) is complete, so every Cuachy sequence of scalars converges to some scalar.

In green: We are showing that $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete. By definition this means that every Cauchy sequence must converge to some function under the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. This is also called uniform convergence.

Comment: Maybe im missing the obvious here but how do we know they are talking about scalars, the vector space is the space of continuous functions so wouldnt $f_k$ be a cont. function? Also where did you get the R and C part from as its not mentioned anywhere in the proof. Im new to functional analysis so still need help with the basic

Comment: In red: We are looking at $\{f_k(x)\}$ which is a sequence of scalars. That $\mathbb{R}$ is complete is almost literally an axiom, and that $\mathbb{C}$ is complete follows from the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ and the definition of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: i get that R and C are complete but how did you deduce that $f_k$ are scalars as it can be a sequence of any continuous functions correct? For example $f_1$ = x where k =1 and $f_2$ = 2x and so on as these are continuous functions for x in [0,1]... that may not be the best example as f is taken to be cauchy but hopefully you get my point

Comment: We fix some $x$. I quote "so $f_k(x)$ converges for each *fixed* $x\in[0,1]$." Thus $f_k(x)$ does not represent the function $f_k$, but rather the function $f_k$ evaluated at the $x$ that we have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In red: because it s puntual convergente and being Cauchy in $\mathbb R$ is equivalente to being convergent.

In green: because convergente in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is exactly The uniform convergence.

Comment: If I understand your first point properly, you're saying that because $f_n$ is pointwise convergent, you have that $f_n(x)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence Cauchy. But, if that's the case, there is no such assumption that $f_n(x)$ pointwise converges. The Cauchiness is proven from the uniform Cauchiness, and convergence is deduced from completeness.